# Detect if the DST is currently enabled

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, timezone, dst

I need to find an easy way to know if the local machine's 'automatically adjust clock for Daylight Saving Time' option is enabled.
If the option's on, I need to know whether it is currently applied (i.e. is it DST currently in the system).
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can find the current system default time zone and whether it is currently using DST (Daylight Saving Time) like this (.NET 3.5 onwards):

```
TimeZoneInfo zone = TimeZoneInfo.Local;
if (zone.SupportsDaylightSavingTime)
{
    Console.WriteLine("System default zone uses DST...");
    Console.WriteLine("In DST? {0}", zone.IsDaylightSavingTime(DateTime.UtcNow));       
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("System default zone does not use DST.");
}
```

Comment: What about using DateTime.IsDaylightSavingTime?

Comment: @hamad: Gosh, I'd never even seen that. Personally I *wouldn't* use it, because a) it doesn't tell you whether the current time zone even supports DST; b) you're really asking a question which is logically about a time zone at a particular point in time - it's a lot more flexible to use the sort of code I've presented IMO; c) it doesn't use the ghastly "let's just use the system default time zone implicitly" aspect of `DateTime`. I'm not a fan of `DateTime`, for various reasons...

Answer (score 2):

Another option may be is `DateTime.IsDaylightSavingTime` method. Check [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.isdaylightsavingtime.aspx).

```
if (DateTime.Now.IsDaylightSavingTime())
    Console.WriteLine("Daylight Saving");
else
    Console.WriteLine("No Daylight Saving");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can read the registry to determine if the checkbox is checked or not.
Read this key,

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\TimeZoneInformation
>   DynamicDaylightTimeDisabled

= 0 or 1 (disabled)

So something like :

```
    Dim retval As Object = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.GetValue("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\TimeZoneInformation", "DynamicDaylightTimeDisabled", 0)
    If retval IsNot Nothing Then
        Select Case CInt(retval)
            Case 0
                Trace.WriteLine("Automatically adjust clock for Daylight Saving Time is checked")
            Case 1
                Trace.WriteLine("Automatically adjust clock for Daylight Saving Time is NOT checked")
        End Select
    End If
```

Comment: This tells if the check box is enabled, but does not tell if DST is currently in effect.

Comment: perhaps that's what some of us want.  I am running a report full of utc dates and  if i did not know the state of that checkbox, and account for it, timezoneinfo will always convert based on it being checked.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another example in C#

```
private static bool IsDayLightSavingsEnabled()
{
  try
  {
    var result = Registry.GetValue(@"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\TimeZoneInformation", "DynamicDaylightTimeDisabled", 1);
    return !Convert.ToBoolean(result); //0 - Checked/enabled,  1 - Unchecked/disabled
  }
  catch
  { }
  return false;
}
```